# Desplegar App en Heroku Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema al desplegar mi App de Heroku la cual en los logs me muestra `4beb-980e-ed445af5a75b fwd="189.215.16.20" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 2022-03-10T05:43:17.367326+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.herokuapp.com`

Investigue un poco y al parecer es un tema con el puerto pero aunque lo configuro en el properties

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Adicional agregue la configuración en el archivo **Procfile**
pero aun así no funciona.

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS
```

Answer (score 0):

te faltaria agregar un archivo en la raiz del proyecto que se llame system.properties que contenga esta linea:

java.runtime.version=1.8   (Aqui pones la version de java con la que estas trabajando, en mi caso la 8).

Tambien te dejo un enlace de un video, con el que me guie para poder que funcionara el despliegue en heroku.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d86xG-UKWB0&t=992s

Saludos.